# JQuery library module export

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, umd

I am trying to understand how jQuery sets itself up.

Right at the beginning jQuery automatically calls a function, which exports a module.

How does the setup work?

Here some more detailed sub-questions which might answer the the more general question:

- What is the use of the recursive call to `function(w)` at `module.exports`?
- What is the use of the `noGlobal` variable?
- Where is the `factory` actually set up and what is its type?
- Why can the `factory` argument get called with one argument and with two as well?
- What is the `global` argument supposed to contain? (I wish there were a type like in c++...)

---

```
(function( global, factory ) {

    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
        // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
        // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
        // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
        // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
        // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
        // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
        // See ticket #14549 for more info.
        module.exports = global.document ?
            factory( global, true ) :
            function( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            };
    } else {
        factory( global );
    }

    // Pass this if window is not defined yet
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is the use of the recursive call to `function(w)` at `module.exports`?

It isn't a recursive call, more of a deferred initialization function. In some CommonJS environments, like Node.JS, the global object does not have a `document` property, while others such as Browserify and Webpack do.

jQuery requires the `document` property to initialize, so it first check to see if the global object contains a `document` property. If it does, it initializes immediately, making in-browser CommonJS environments happy. If it does not, it returns a function that can be used to later initialize jQuery. This function could later be called on a fake window, creating with something like jsdom.

---

> What is the use of the `noGlobal` variable?

The `noGlobal` variable is used here.

**[Excerpt from jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1472290917f17af05e98007136096784f9051fab/dist/jquery.js#L10339-L10344):**

```
// Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in
// AMD (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
// and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
if ( typeof noGlobal === strundefined ) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

Essentially, if `noGlobal` is `undefined`, jQuery will add itself to the global `window` object. The only time it will not do this is if it is loaded by a CommonJS loader, with a `document` property on the global object, such as Browserify or Webpack. The call below is where `noGlobal` is not `undefined`.

```
factory( global, true )
```

---

> Where is the `factory` actually set up and what is its type?

The `factory` variable is a `function`, and it is declared here:

```
function( window, noGlobal ) {
```

It is the second argument passed into the [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).

---

> Why can the `factory` argument get called with one argument and with two as well?

Because JavaScript.

In JavaScript, there is no requirement to match the number of arguments a function is declared with. Any omitted arguments have the value `undefined`.

---

> What is the `global` argument supposed to contain? (I wish there were a type like in c++...)

It is supposed to contain the global object for the JavaScript environment. In a browser, this object is known as `window`, and in Node, this object is known as `global`. In both environments, using `this` in the global scope will resolve to the global object, whatever it's global name is.

However, due to some 3rd-party wrappers which can change the scope in which jQuery is initialized, jQuery will first check if the `window` object is available and use it if it is. If not use, it will default to using `this`.

```
typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this
```

---

> one more question: where is the w argument coming from?

When the global object does not contain a `document`, it returns a function that accepts one argument, the `w`. This object would be a `window`-like object with a `document` that can be created with something like jsdom.

Comment: one more question: where is the w argument coming from?

Comment: @Beginner When the global object does not contain a `document`, it returns a function that accepts one argument, the `w`. This object would be a `window`-like object with a `document` that can be created with something like jsdom.

Comment: Does this mean w is a global variable which is available in the case that no document is available?

Comment: Not exactly. When jQuery does not have global document, it will instead return a function which can later be used to init jQuery. To do that, you would call that function, and pass in the window-like object you want to initialize it on. The window-like object is something you would have to create, with something like jsdom and pass when you want to initialize it. Something like this: `var $ = require('jquery')(myFakeWindow);`, where `myFakeWindow` is the window-like object you created.

Comment: Ok, I got it: w is an argument to a function defined exactly at this location. It is a free variable which does not need to be defined at this point, right?

Comment: @Beginner It's technically an argument, not a free variable, but yes, jQuery does not define it. You would pass it in when you want to use it.